# Different results with Microsoft Translator API / Web Translator

Tags: microsoft-translator, machine-translation

I am running test to select an MT API, and while testing the Microsoft Translator have found that I get different results for the same sentence using the API from a script than what I get when passing the whole URL to the Web Translator.

For this sentence in EN source:

*AppFlow is supported on NetScaler appliances running version 9.3 and above with nCore build*.

(first FAQ in https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/12-1/networking-faq/appflow-faq.html)

I get this result for FR, when passing that single sentence for translation in the https://www.bing.com/translator page and via a Python script calling the API:

*AppFlow est pris en charge sur les appliances NetScaler qui exécutent la version 9,3 et plus avec ncore Build.*

However, the same sentence in the whole translated URL in Web Translator reads:

*AppFlow est pris en charge sur les appliances NetScaler exécutant la version 9.3 et ci-dessus avec nCore construire.*

(https://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=en&to=fr&a=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.citrix.com%2Fen-us%2Fnetscaler%2F12-1%2Fnetworking-faq%2Fappflow-faq.html)

My understanding is that the API now works with NMT by default. I would like to understand why Web Translator presents a different result. I was going to do some assessment by passing URLs into Web Translator, but if this is not using the API with NMT, then I cannot use this method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 3 of the Translator API defaults to NMT. http://bing.com/translator also defaults to NMT.
The full web page translation in bing.com and the Edge browser extension still use SMT for most language pairs, including English<>French. This is for scalability reasons.

Comment: Above answer is not true anymore. All is Neural MT now.